# port forwarding from internet to inner router

Tags: port-forwarding, webserver, mikrotik-routeros

I'm trying to port forward from internet through a main mikrotik router (192.168.1.0/24) to a second Router on another subnet 192.168.2.0/24 to reach a DVR at 192.168.2.20

I can see the DVR web page but typing User & password not works, it seems like DVR don't know how to reach back the internet address

Comment: If you can get to the web page, then it's sending things back fine. We need more specific to be able to help.  Please explain your network settings (in the context of what you're trying to accomplish here), and what you've tried already in attempts to pinpoint a culprit.  IE Does the DVR UI respond as expected if you hit it directly? How about if you hit it from the outside address of the inside router?

Comment: Unless you have a good reason to segregate the second subnet from the first, it's generally a bad idea to run a NAT enabled router behind another one.  Even if you do need the segregation, there's usually better alternatives than a second router, for instance a virtual LAN, although that's not always possible.

Comment: Using internal address (192.168.2.20) works fine, I can ping Internet address from inside router but can´t see web page

Comment: I have Internet access on site 1, site 2 (dvr Location) route all  internet access from site 1.

Answer (score 0):

Confirm this:

- Mikrotik has an dst-nat rule in IP FIREWALL NAT with dst-port 80 to dst-address 192.168.2.20
- Mikrotik knows 192.168.2.0/24 route in IP ROUTE
- Second router has default gw to 192.168.1.1/24
- DVR has default gw -second router-

It's possible that DVR is using https, or another ports to acces it? You must redirect all of used ports.